# Copying ALL tables from one user to another Oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g, copy

I have a user name user1 with a password user1
I want to create a user 2 identified by user 2 and copy all the tables with all the data from user 1 to user 2.

Can I copy all the tables at once, or I need to copy table by table to the new user?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataPump.
First of all, create a directory object that maps to a directory in your file system:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIR_TEMP AS 'C:\temp';
```

Then export your schema (associated with user1) in a dump file:

```
C:\app\...\dbhome_1\BIN\expdp.exe system/pwd SCHEMAS=USER_1 DIRECTORY=DIR_TEMP DUMPFILE=file.dmp LOGFILE=file_exp.log
```

And finally re-import your dump file:

```
C:\app\...\dbhome_1\BIN\impdp.exe system/pwd REMAP_SCHEMA=USER_1:USER_2 DIRECTORY=DIR_TEMP DUMPFILE=file.dmp LOGFILE=file_imp.log
```

Comment: Forgot to mention my system runs on Debian

Comment: No problem, DataPump works on every platform. You have to use a different path syntax (e.g. /u01/... instead of c:\...).